# Why does CGContextSetShadowWithColor change the current fill color, too?

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics

I'm overriding `-drawRect:` to draw some custom views. Usually, I'm drawing a filled rounded rect bezier path with a drop shadow. However, I've run into an annoying issue: when I set the shadow color, the fill color is also changed to the same color!

Is this a bug in Core Graphics or am I missing something here? Here's an example of my code where I'm trying to draw a path with a shadow. `translucentBlack` and `highlight` are two different `UIColor` objects, but what gets drawn is a rounded rect that is filled with the highlight color as well as the shadow in the highlight color.

```
UIBezierPath* blackTranslucentRoundedRectPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 5, CGRectGetWidth(frame) - 10, CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 10) cornerRadius: 8];
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, highlightOffset, highlightBlurRadius, highlight.CGColor);
[translucentBlack setFill];
[blackTranslucentRoundedRectPath fill];
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thank god somebody upvoted this question. Makes me feel less uniquely stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you can see your highlight color through your **translucent** black color. Change the `translucentBlack` to any non-transparent color (make its alpha equal 1.0)  and you should be fine.

Comment: son of a @%#$, duh. I completely spaced on this. Somehow, I was thinking that the shadow would only be drawn outside of the path and not behind the path as well.